# Cypress - Waiting on canceled XHR Request

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, intercept

I have the intended functionality of canceling a pending XHR request in the application. I want to verify that the request is canceled after invoking the cancel action.

Right now I have this:

```
cy.intercept('GET', '**/request/**').as('Request');
invokeRequest();
invokeCancel();
cy.wait('@Request');
```

However, cypress is timing out on the cy.wait(). Is there a way to verify the request has been canceled?

Comment: It currently doesn't look possible; there's a Cypress issue tracking this at https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/19326